# git-mv showing file deleted

Tags: git

When I run `git-mv file1 file2`, I get the file moved from `file1` to `file2` as I'd expect. Sometimes, though, my `git status` gives me 'odd' output.

When I run `git-mv f1 f2`, then `git status`:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   renamed:    f1 -> f2
```

That's what I'd expect. Other times, though, after I've committed `f2`, I get:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage) 
#
#   deleted:    f1
```

This generally happens after I've committed the new file. I don't know *why* it happens - it seems to occur at random (because generally I get the `renamed: f1->f2` message, like I'm expecting).

I'd like to know why I sometimes get messages saying I've deleted the file after I run `git mv`, and what steps I'd have gone through to produce this - I've just tried to reproduce, and got `renamed:..`; but 10 minutes ago I got a `deleted:...` on a file I'd `git-mv`ed about 10 minutes before *that*. It's confusing me greatly.

Comment: When you look at the commit where you renamed the file in question (e.g. in gitk), do you see that you actually just committed an add of the new-named file? Have you done anything besides make a sequence of commits (reset back, nontrivial branching, etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you renamed `f1` to `f2`, but only committed the addition of `f2` and not the removal of `f1`. This can happen if you use `git mv f1 f2` but then type `git commit f2`, or it can happen if you type `mv f1 f2` and then do something like `git add .; git commit`

Answer (score 3):

Moving files in git really is just deleting the old + creating a new file.

The "renamed: ..:" output is just a heuristic, and apparently git gets it wrong sometimes, even if it's obvious.

Comment: Thanks Dominik. So it's a heuristic, a guess... this actually makes more sense with what I'm seeing.  Between commits I both renamed (with git mv) AND then overwrote a bunch of jar files with newer versions.  For some files, git status shows delete and add, for others it shows rename.  And even when you do git mv, maybe it's just a convenience for git rm + git add, and it STILL guesses, even though you specifically said git mv... But sure seems odd to use Subversion converts.

Answer (score 3):

Git doesn't track moves in the file history like Subversion does: the history just stores the content, and `git log` &c. look at the file contents and what changed to deduce whether a change was a rename. Thus, `git mv f1 f2` is equivalent to:

```
mv f1 f2
git rm f1
git add f2
```

The removal of f1 and the addition of f2 are completely different changes as far as Git is concerned, so if you now do `git commit f2`, you only commit the addition of f2, and the removal of f1 is still an uncommitted change. To make sure you commit both changes, do `git commit` with no arguments to commit everything, or `git commit f1 f2` to commit just the changes to those two files, or use `git commit --interactive` or some other tool to edit the *index* in a more complicated way. (The *index* is the list of "changes to be committed".)