# Git: folder with same name as root ignored

Tags: git

Assume the following folder structure

```
- myproj
  - components
    - server
      - src
```

Now I moved all source files in `src` to a subfolder called like the root, `myproj` (due to `PATH` reasons). The tree now looks like this

```
- myproj
  - components
    - server
      - src
        - myproj
```

Git only shows deletions, but not the new files in the `myproj` subfolder. Why?

#### Update:

I explicitly invoked `git add` on the new directory and it reported

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
  components/server/src/<myproj>
```

Apparently a "rogue" `.gitignore` snuck in somehow in a project subfolder, excluding the name - so I assumed it was root folder name related - but it's not.

Comment: Have you said `git add myproj/components/server/src/myproj`?

Comment: What do you have in all your `.gitignore`s in the repo? What is about `.git/info/exclude` `git config core.excludesfile`?

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't show deletion if you are using [`git mv`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv), followed by a `git commit`.

If you don't, then it detect deletions, and addition.

Make sure you commit everything, and not just `git commit myproj` after the move, or the status would still reflect deletion as in "[`git mv` does not delete old file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9610786/6309)".

If you just move the files under a new directory, be aware that a `git status` will only show you that new directory (not all the files in it).

It is only when you `git add myproj` that you would see in the `git status` all the files within it.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't detect the moved files AT ALL! gitignore is empty.